# XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException after <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to make application with Spring. After I put `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to my xml configuration I received XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException.

xml config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="java"/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="beanOne" class="BeanOne"></bean>
<bean id="beanTwo" class="BeanTwo"></bean>
<bean id="Three" class="BeanThree"></bean>
<bean id="aspect" class="AspClass"></bean>
</beans>
```

Text in console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
  Line 12 in XML document from class path resource [context.xml] is invalid;
  nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
  lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 29; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c:
  The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found
  for element 'aop:aspectj-autoproxy'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)*
```

Can you tell me what should I do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you should get rid of the non-existent `xmlns:p` and instead add the schema location for `aop` instead.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
>
  <context:component-scan base-package="java"/>

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

  <bean id="beanOne" class="BeanOne"></bean>
  <bean id="beanTwo" class="BeanTwo"></bean>
  <bean id="Three" class="BeanThree"></bean>
  <bean id="aspect" class="AspClass"></bean>
</beans>
```